# Two Paperclip attachments pointing to same file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Is it possible to copy a Paperclip attachment from one model to another without creating new files? In other words: Can two Paperclip instances point to the same file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Paperclip doesn't support this.

And even if you managed to do this manually by manipulating values in the database, imagine what will happen, if one of the records is deleted...